# An equality on size of subset of hypercube

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, reference-request

Let $\bar C$ be set of all vertices of a hypercube in $\mathbb{R}^n$, taking coordinate $(c_1,\dots,c_n)$ in which $c_i=0,1$. $C$ is a subset of $\bar C$. For $A\subseteq\{1,\dots,n\}$ be a set of axis of coordinate, define projection of $C$ on $A$ to be $C|_A=\{(c_i,\dots,c_j):A=\{i,\dots,j\},\,\exists(c^{\prime}_1,\dots,c^{\prime}_n)\in C,\, c^{\prime}_i=c_i \text{ for all } i\in A\}$. Then I guess:
$$\sum_{A\subseteq\{1,\dots,n\}}(-1)^{n-\#A}\#C|_A=\begin{cases}
1, & \text{if }C=\bar C \\
0, & \text{if }C\not=\bar C
\end{cases}$$

if and only if $C$, with abuse of terminology, is a partial cube of $\bar C$.

For example $C=\{(0,0),(0,1),(1,0)\}$, $\#C|_{\{1,2\}}=3$,  $\#C|_{\{1\}}=2$,  $\#C|_{\{2\}}=2$, $\#C|_{\emptyset}=1$, so left hand side is $0$, the equality holds, and we have $C$ is a partial cube. And when $C=\{(0,1),(1,0)\}$, $\#C|_{\{1,2\}}=2$,  $\#C|_{\{1\}}=2$,  $\#C|_{\{2\}}=2$, $\#C|_{\emptyset}=1$, so left hand side is $-1$, in this case $C$ is not a partial cube.

I believe that should be a problem that has been studied, can any one help me with finding some reference on it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I see strong relation to the [inclusion-exclusion principle](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Inclusion-ExclusionPrinciple.html).

Comment: Your defined quantity looks a little bit like the Beta invariant for matroids which has been studied in the literature a little bit: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matroid#Beta_invariant